What is the dark brown gas emission seen during the ascent of Starship?
During the video (see below) of Starship IFT-4 there is a lot of brown smoke or gas in the Superheavy exhaust from near the start for almost 30 seconds. Is this NO2? If so roughly how much is produced?




The brown emission is most likely methane soot. Although methane/oxygen flames are “cleaner” than heavier hydrocarbons, they do still produce soot, especially under fuel-rich situations.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0082078475804012
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19760023300

I do think it is some nitrogen oxides (NOx) the temperatures in the exhaust are reasonable for NOx to be produced plus the orange-brown colour is that of nitrogen dioxide, and if someone asks but there is no nitrogen in the fuel, that is pretty obvious, its atmospheric nitrogen that's one of the main reasons why we have catalytic converters because the combustion in a car engine mind you with atmospheric oxygen can produce NOx, in a very optimised combustion such that in the   raptor engine I think there is enough thermal energy to form nitrogen oxides, and if methane did produce that much soot gas burners would be very dirty but they burn clean majority of the time, but yes I believe it is nitrogen oxides

https://www.eurekalert.org/news-releases/952459#:~:text=The%20researchers%20found%20the%20production,altitude%20of%20approximately%2010%20km.

NO2 is a plausible explanation for the appearance of the plume. For instance, "Nitrogen Dioxide (NO2) is a pungent gas that, along with fine airborne particulate matter, contributes to the reddish-brown haze characteristic of smoggy air in California." [ https://ww2.arb.ca.gov/resources/nitrogen-dioxide-and-health ]. I may be hard to know without an in-depth scientific investigation to determine how much of the appearance is due to soot and how much might be due to NO2.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
